# How to use equalsIgnoreCase() for multiple elements in java

Tags: java

```
if(string.equalsIgnoreCase("first") || 
string.equalsIgnoreCase("second") || string.equalsIgnoreCase("third"))
```

I need to use 10 `||` here (I have 10 strings to check).Is there any simple solution for this.

And i need to find which condition is satisfied.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to know which match is true, then use a switch (Java 7 only):

```
switch (string.toLowerCase())
{
    case "first": doSomething();
        break;
    case "second": ...;
        break;
    default: ...;
}
```

Comment: Please be mindful that this idiom can lead to surprising results depending on the current *locale* with non-ascii characters.

Comment: You're right, I never think ahead and never had to deal with such locales, so I don't take that into account.

Answer (score 9):

You could use `string.matches()` which takes a regular expression into which you can coerce first, second third etc:

```
if (string.matches("first|second|third"))
```

or, for case insensitivity:

```
if (string.matches("(?i)first|second|third"))
```

Regular expressions are complex though so could be a performance issue.

Comment: is there any possibility to know which match is true

Comment: If this is what you do in the method, see my answer about switches.

Comment: No, it's equivalent to your multiple || in the question. If you want to know which match, probably the best thing to do is split up the 'if'. You could still use regular expressions for common elements. Or switch on strings and make use of 'follow through'.

Comment: Sorry, was writing this before I saw Djon's comment: indeed, consider a switch.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use a `Set<String>` and check whether it *contains* the desired `String`.

```
TreeSet<String> values = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

values.put("first");
values.put("second");
values.put("third");

if (values.contains(string.toLower())) {
}
```

This works in *logarithmic time* (`O(log n)`), whereas the `||`-approach is (theoretically in worst case) linear. For 10 elements it's hardly relevant though.

**Edit (credits go to Walter):**

The `TreeSet` class uses the `Comparator` only to determine equality, rather than using `equals` method. You can therefore put mixed case strings into it. From the [Class TreeSet documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit
>   comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to
>   correctly implement the Set interface. (See Comparable or Comparator
>   for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so
>   because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation,
>   but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its
>   compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal
>   by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The
>   behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent
>   with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set
>   interface.

Comment: Or use `new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)`.

Comment: But the values don't need to be sorted here.

Comment: @WalterLaan I need to try it out later on, but I think the comparator only changes the *sort order*, but not the fact that `contains` uses `equals` to check whether an element is the one being searched for.

Comment: @Djon `TreeSet` sorts the element to build a tree for fast lookup. They therefore need to be sorted, though I agree this is not of interest to PSR.

Comment: @MatthiasMeid My bad, I was refering to a `Set` in general, that the values don't need to be sorted in order to find if it contains one. I don't think it is faster to have the values sorted when you are looking for a random value in the set.

Comment: @Djon I agree for a set of like 10 elements. `TreeSet` stores elements in a sorted fashion by design. One could also use a `HashSet` or any other implementation. After all I'd go for your `switch` approach anyway in this case, since the values are known at compile time.

Comment: @MatthiasMeid contains will also use the compare method: `a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface.`

Answer (score 2):

you can use your own function:

`equalsIgnoreCase("string", "first", "second");`

```
public boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String needle, String... haystack) {
    foreach(String s : haystack) {
        if(needle.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why does it return false on finding a match?

Comment: @JamesDaily: Very good question, probably too early in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Java 8 and streams solution

```
String string = "...";

List<String> match = Arrays.asList("first", "second", "third", "...");

if (match.stream().anyMatch(string::equalsIgnoreCase)) {
    // ...
}
```